# Cómo mandar datos de dos o mas tablas una vista create laravel

Tags: laravel

Controller producto

```
public function create()
    {    
        $datoCategoria = categorias::pluck('nomCategoria', 'idCategoria')->prepend('Seleccione categoria');

        return view('listado/productos/create')->with('datoCategoria', $datoCategoria);

        $datoProveedor = proveedores::pluck('nomProveedor', 'idProveedor')->prepend('Seleccione Proveedor');

        return view('listado/productos/create')->with('datoProveedor', $datoProveedor);  

    }
```

Formulario crear producto

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!!form::label('Proveedor')!!}
    {!!form::select('idProveedor', $datoProveedor, null,['id'=>'idProveedor', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!!form::label('Categoria')!!}
    {!!form::select('idCategoria', $datoCategoria, null,['id'=>'idCategoria', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

Error

> "Undefined variable: datoProveedor (View:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/listado/resources/views/listado/productos/create.blade.php)"

Si solo mando uno, proveedor o categoría, si funciona

Comment: y si pruebas mandandolos a todas las variables dentro de un array asociativo y en vez de hacer 2 return view solo haces uno con esto mira ->with(['datoCategoria' => $datoCategoria,
        'datoProveedor' => $datoProveedor]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes mandar múltiples variables a una sola vista en Laravel con ayuda del método `with()` del modo siguiente, en forma de array asociativo es decir como `clave => valor`

```
 $datoCategoria = categorias::pluck('nomCategoria', 'idCategoria')
 ->prepend('Seleccione categoria');
 $datoProveedor = proveedores::pluck('nomProveedor', 'idProveedor')      
 ->prepend('Seleccione Proveedor');

return view('listado/productos/create')
                     ->with([
                            'datoCategoria' => $datoCategoria, 
                            'datoProveedor' => $datoProveedor
                           ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo enviando con ambos datos tu vista así:

```
$datoCategoria = categorias::pluck('nomCategoria', 'idCategoria')->prepend('Seleccione categoria');

$datoProveedor = proveedores::pluck('nomProveedor', 'idProveedor')->prepend('Seleccione Proveedor');

$data = [
    'datoCategoria'  => $datoCategoria,
    'datoProveedor' => $datoProveedor
];

return view('listado/productos/create')->with($data);
```

Tu vista ahora podrá usar ambos datos de proveedor y categoría